# Cannot connect to server. Too many symbolic links. Postgres Error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I get this error when I try connecting to a PostgreSQL server:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Too many levels of symbolic links
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

What can I do to fix this?

I have Postgres installed on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432. And if it is symlink, what it points to.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I didn't request clarification nor critiqued. What I wrote is (in my opinon) provided answer to question: "What can I do to fix it?". Checking symlinks is first step on fixing.